# What were the first publication dates of the Big Bads in the Elder Evils?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

[*Elder Evils*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_Evils) (2007) is a supplement for world or multiverse-ending Big Bads published by Wizards of the Coast. It contains nine primary antagonists (see below) with a host of subordinate or supporting lesser antagonists for each. I noticed that at least one of these (based on name, form, and defining traits), Zargon, originally appeared in the D&D module *B4 The Lost City*.

*Elder Evils* does a poor job citing the source material for its contents, and I want to know when and where these first appeared in TSR or Wizards of the Coast publications (notes about appearances in other media welcome, but not the direct answer I am looking for):

1. Atropus
2. Father Llymic
3. The Hulks of Zoretha
4. The Leviathan
5. The Pandorym
6. Ragnorra
7. Sertrous
8. The Worm that Walks
9. Zargon (1982, [*B4 The Lost City*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lost_City_(Dungeons_%26_Dragons)))

Answer (score 2):

### Some appear in earlier editions

- The Leviathan

  - The earliest mention of the Leviathan is found in 1981 in *Dragon* magazine #46.

    > The walls are covered with bas reliefs [sic] of tremendous sea beasts, such as the Great White Shark, Leviathan, and Devil Kraken.
- The Pandorym

  - The Pandorym first appeared in the 2006 novel [*Darkvision*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkvision_(novel)) by Bruce Cordell.
- The Worm that Walks

  - Kyuss first appeared in 2006 in *Dungeon* magazine #130.
  - Sons of Kyuss first appeared in the *Fiend Folio* in 1981.
- Zargon

  - As you noted, appeared first in the 1982 module *The Lost City*.

### The rest

As far as I know, the remaining Elder Evils you list do not appear prior to the release of *Elder Evils* in 2007.

Comment: While not disputing the fact that the Leviathan was mentioned in Dragon #46, I suspect that one may be a case of two things drawing on the same original source rather than a direct link from one to the other.

Comment: The name Sertrous appears in Barrow of the Forgotten King (Feb 2007) and Sinister Spire (Jun 2007). Elder Evils was published Dec 2007 so this may be an intentional tie-in. Leviathan appears in Return to White Plume Mountain (1999), though this is marked as not its original appearance in D&D, and it is not fully clear if this is exactly the same creature. The [spotlight interview](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd%2F4spot%2F20071210a) seems to suggest that the elder evils are mostly original creations except for Zargon and Kyuss.